# REST API Call from curl

Tags: magento1.9.3

I have configured all things by going `System->Webservices` menu, submenus that start with REST. And then I test in `myDomainname/api/rest/`, but it shows a **404** error like

> "Request does not match any route".

It is shown the guide tutorial in 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html 
 here, not fully. I need to show all orders details, details. But I can't understand what is next procedure is after `configuring/setting up. I need a total step-by-step procedure after configuring in` System-> Webservice->REST`.

Under configuration, I created a rule as an assigned user to that

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Do you want to create own api or use existing?

Comment: i want to use existing

Comment: rest api giving ma an 404 error

Answer (score 0):

SOAP V1: http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl (this one is more like RPC, no concrete operations defined in WSDL, just call)
SOAP V2: http://magentohost/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1 .

For strongly-typed languages use this one and remember to enable WS-I compliance mode on Magento side: `Services > Magento Core API > WS-I Compliance to Yes`

http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-v2-soap-demystified/
also check [SOAP API Call not working with Magento 1.9.1.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55135/soap-api-call-not-working-with-magento-1-9-1-0)

There is everything.. First few results in google ;)

Comment: And where is the REST in that?